# Subtracting the sum of flows on one date from the sum of another date?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum

I need help figuring out how to write a query that will look up the SUM value of my Flows for two specific dates and subtract one from the other.

Essentially I need to find the SUM of the Flows for 10/30/2015 and subtract it from the SUM of the Flows on 12/31/2014 in order to get the YTD Change. The query bellow is what I have so far. It gives me exactly what I need for that specific day, however now I need to be able to run the calculation as well in order to get the YTD.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT NAME, SUM(FLOWS/1000000.00) AS FLOWS
FROM HISTORY_TBL1
WHERE DATE = TO_DATE('10302015','MMDDYYYY')
GROUP BY NAME
ORDER BY FLOWS DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM <=10
```

Comment: why do you need the "GROUP BY NAME" part ?? since it's not mentioned in the question..

Comment: @nabeel Its because each product may have more than one value for any particular day and I need all the transactions for each name to be grouped together and the result set of a sum value per day per product (Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the two values and their difference:

```
SELECT NAME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = DATE '2014-12-31' THEN FLOWS END)/1000000.00 AS FLOWS_20141231,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = DATE '2015-10-30' THEN FLOWS END)/1000000.00 AS FLOWS_20151030,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE = DATE '2015-10-30' THEN FLOWS
                WHEN DATE = DATE '2014-12-31' THEN - FLOWS
           END)/1000000.00 AS FLOWS_DIFF,
FROM HISTORY_TBL1
WHERE DATE IN (DATE '2015-10-30',  DATE '2014-12-31')
GROUP BY NAME;
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the reults.

Comment: I need to be able to calculate the YTD change. Which means that I need to take the sum value of the last business day (10/30/2015) and subtract it by the sum of the last business day of last year (12/31/2014). The result of this equation is the YTD Change.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME,
       SUM(
          CASE 
          WHEN DATE=TO_DATE('10302015','MMDDYYYY') THEN FLOWS    -- the bigger number
          WHEN DATE=TO_DATE('12312014','MMDDYYYY') THEN FLOWS * -1 -- minus the smaller number
          ELSE 0 
          END
       )/1000000.00 AS FLOWS_2015_minus_2014
FROM HISTORY_TBL1
WHERE DATE IN ( TO_DATE('10302015','MMDDYYYY'),
        TO_DATE('12312014','MMDDYYYY'))
GROUP BY NAME;
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what it is that I'm looking and I'm sorry if I'm not clear in my question. I simply want to get the sums for each name on 10/30/2015 and subtract them by the sums of each name on 12/31/2014. I just need to be able to write a query that will do that simple calculation so that I can avoid doing the calculations in excel.

Comment: that's exactly what this query returns, count of 31-DEC minus count of 30-OCT

Comment: I ran this query and it gave me a result set of two columns. The column by the name of NAME has all of my products in it and the Column named FLOWS_DEC_MINUS_OCT gave me a result set of -1 on each and every one of the products. Basically the result set did not have any calculations at all. Also I don't understand why I would need the count when I'm looking for the sum!

Comment: answer updated with correct data/format and sum instead of count